# Which django apps are directly usable or easily adaptable for django-nonrel?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

Is there a list of django apps that can be used unaltered in django-nonrel or a list of django apps that can be easily adapted to be used in django-nonrel?

Answer (score 1):

I used [django-dbindexer](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/09/Get-SQL-features-on-NoSQL-with-django-dbindexer) from the same guys that made django-nonrel to use [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) without modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found such a list.
For the record, I've gotten tastypie working with tiny modifications 
http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/12076483835/tastypie-on-django-nonrel-on-app-engine

django-merchant seems to be working as well.
https://github.com/agiliq/merchant

Essentially simple apps that don't require JOINs in their DB queries will most likely work.  If they use ManyToManyRelations, they're probably not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used 'contenttypes, auth and sessions' from 'django.contrib' without any modification, the app code wont cause any problems. However any query using JOINs result in query errors, so you need to write your queries with this limitation in mind.

Did you have a particular app in mind?